# Дoлгий ответ от сервера ВК

Tags: vkontakte-api

Очень долгий ответ от сервера ВК. В чем может быть дело?

```
echo '<pre>';
foreach ($clubs as $club) {
    $posts = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api. vk. com/method/wall.get?count=100&owner_id=-'.$club.'&filter=others&v=5'), true);
    foreach ($posts['response']['items'] as $post) {
        if ($post['from_id'] == $user_id) {
            print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.  com/method/wall.delete?owner_id=-'.$club.'&post_id='.$post['id'].'&v=5&access_token='.$token), true));
        }
    }
    print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api .vk. com/method/wall.post?owner_id=-'.$club.'&v=5&message='.urlencode($message).'&access_token='.$token), true));
    echo '<pre>';
}
?>
```

Comment: сделал пробел между ссылками!!

не обращайте на это внимания

Comment: вк в последнее время тупит, так что не удивительно. А вообще у вас может с сетью проблемы. Хотя в данном случае скорее всего надо просто контекст передать с "Connection: Close" (как-то так). UPD: [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629504) пример приведен

Comment: как вариант переписать на curl, тогда и проблемы не будет, и ошибки информативнее будут

Comment: Пожалуйста, больше не используйте КАПС в вопросах.

Comment: @Sergiks Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

1. возможно, вы бомбите API слишком частыми запросами – ВКонтакте разрешают [не более 3 запросов в секунду](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests), потом возвращают [ошибки](https://vk.com/dev/errors), вместо ожидаемого вами `response`;
2. вы бомбите *однообразными* запросами – ВКонтакте не афиширует свои точные лимиты, но частый вызов метода `wall.post()` они точно не пропустят – вернут, опять же, ошибку. Как вариант, могут [затребовать решение капчи](https://vk.com/dev/captcha_error);

Итого – предусмотрите возможность, что ответ api не будет содержать свойства `response`, а вместо него появится св-во `error` – обрабатывайте такие ошибки.